# Bringing changes to an experimental branch from a new commit in git svn

Tags: git, svn

I have the following git svn situation.

1. master, checked out from svn.
2. branched devel branch, on which I did some changes. Some are git committed, some are still not committed.
3. I had to solve a bug, so I stashed my non-committed stuff, switched branch to master, `git svn rebase` to update, created and switched to a branch `bugfix`.
4. fixed the bug in `bugfix`, committed.
5. switched to master, svn merge from bugfix.
6. git svn dcommit.
7. Now I am ready to resume my work in `devel`, however I want to bring the recent bugfix in my branch without messing up things.

What should I do now, in order to guarantee I don't mess up everything when I finally end my work in `devel` and merge --squash onto master followed by the dcommit ? I am not ready to linearize, so I cannot do a git rebase on devel from the master (which would, as far as I get, put all my changes from `devel` in front of the latest `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a simple *git cherry-pick* of your bugfix commit do the trick ?

Comment: don't know. I feel like I am walking on glasses with git. I am still learning it, with the additional trouble of having to interact with svn.

Comment: Yeah, I perfectly see what you mean... After awhile things are getting better and you can really appreciate the power of Git when you feel more confortable with it. I use git through svn as well by the way. I think if you just need to report one or two commits from a branch to an other, cherry picking could be a good option for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks. When I merge, of course the two modifications will not conflict.

Comment: When you will merge back, or rebase back, Git should be smart enough to realize that those commits exists on both branches and just skip them (otherwise you can also perform an interactive rebase, 'git rebase -i', and check those commits as skipped by yourself).